# Transparent element not letting me click stuff

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a selling webpage which uses Asp.net and CSS. Something is overlaying the text boxes and hyperlinks so it doesn't allow me to click in to them when using a mobile device. I've tried eeverything I know and wondered if anyone would be so kind to try and help me with this by looking at the page souce code and using Inspect Element as I'm quite new to programming and not sure how to use it fully.

The web page is http://www.onlinecarbooty.com/go-booting2.aspx
BUT you need to be logged in using..
Username: test12345@aol.com and Password: qwerty
on this page: http://www.onlinecarbooty.com/loginmob.aspx

As I say, it works on a laptop but on a mobile you can't click anything apart from the photos (sellers items).

The code is big and will confuse matters if I post it here so if possible, can anyone please have a look at the page directly for me. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can take a look, but credentials you provide seems to be wrong.

Edit:

All right. You can put in the CSS file this code:

```
.stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  width: 320px;
  pointer-events: none;
}


.stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div select, .stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div textarea, .stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div input, .stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Edited:

Your html is very messy and it should be refactored. Above I use `pointer-events` attribute which allows element to be transparent, so you can click through it, however if you want to specific elements of the elements which attribute `pointer-events: none` to be clickable you have to set their attribute to `pointer-events: auto`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, they should work fine now. Thank you for anything you can do.

Comment: Adding these css styles to #MainContent_lsvBootSaleOrders_upStalls_0 > div seems to do the job.

    `position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    left: 50%;`

Comment: That's great news, thanks. Where do I find that Div please ? At the top of the asp code it says <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server"> which is the only reference to 'mainContent'. The only things I know how to change are the aspx files, layout.css file and I also have access to the database. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry I am not into ASP so without seeing the project files I cannot say much.

Comment: Is there any chance you can show me a screen shot of where you added it and then I should be able to wok it out from there. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ah right great thank you.. I've just added that and it ALMOST works. The picture slider works for the first seller and I can click in the message box etc but for the sellers underneath the picture slider doesn't work. This is on my Android Samsung A5 phone. I'm guessing I have something out of alignment still ? Soooo close, thank you again.

Comment: I think this finally could help you get through it. I edited answer above.

Comment: It's actually all working apart from the slider.. you can only move the slider left and right using the exremem left and right of the screen. Is there a tweak for that at all ? If not, thank you so much again and I will be tidying up the html now :-)

Comment: I don not see the `pointer-events: none` on `.stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div`. Have try to set it?

Comment: I've added it so my css looks like this..
.stallNew
{
    width:100%;
    height:682px;
    background-image:url(/files/images/stallNew.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom;
}

.stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
}

.stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div select, .stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div textarea, .stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div input, .stallNew > div:nth-child(2) > div a { pointer-events: auto;
}

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/d1m2S

Comment: Hehe! You're a genius. I can't thank you enough. I'm going to have some very happy sellers here! Thank you for explaining it in easy to understand terms too. I don't understand everything, but quite a lot of what you've said makes sense. I will work on my skills. Thank you :-)

Comment: I will tidy up the rest of the page, html and need to increase thumbnail resolution then this should be looking great thanks to you. You're a superstar !